# How to run a wordpress.com hosted website locally using docker?

Tags: wordpress, docker

Currently we have a WooCommerce webshop hosted on wordpress.com. This webshop was setup as a prototype and because of its succes we want to start developing the webshop further. We don't want to change the production website directly, but we want to develop inside a closed development environment (e.g. locally using docker).

I have tried to run the webshop locally by exporting all its data using the [All-in-One WP Migration](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) plugin. Afterwards I have created a docker environment with a [wordpress](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) and a [mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) container. On the wordpress container I've also installed the All-in-One WP Migration plugin and I've imported all the data. It looked like this worked fine, but after a few clicks I saw that I could not navigate to any other URL besides the homepage. I have read online that the Wordpress codebase being used on wordpress.com differs from the default codebase which can be download on wordpress.org. So I think this means the wordpress.com export file can't be imported into a default wordpress container.

Because of this I've tried to download all the files on wordpress.com using FTP and run the website myself using a [php](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) container. This also didn't work, because I can't download all the files using FTP because of the permissions. I also contacted the support of wordpress.com, and they told me they couldn't sent me the contents of these files. But without these files, I don't know how I can run the wordpress.com website locally.

I hope someone can help me with getting the wordpress.com website to run locally in a development environment. A suggestion how we can implement a workflow where we can change the webshop in a development environment and deploy the changes to our production website is also very welcome.

Edit: For now I've chosen to run my site in a docker environment and write down all the changes I make locally. When I'm satisfied with the site locally, I will repeat the changes I made earlier on the production website. I've chosen this workflow because I don't really know the structures inside Wordpress. I don't know how I can migrate the files and database tables I need to switch theme, without overwriting the database tables I want to keep (e.g. WooCommerce orders table).

Comment: "So I think this means the wordpress.com export file can't be imported into a default wordpress container." Yes, you can: https://move.wordpress.com/exportimport-content/. The problem with URLs throwing 404 errors lies elsewhere. Try re-saving the permalinks and see if that helps, otherwise it might be a Docker-related configuration issue.

Comment: @cabrerahector your hint about re-saving the permalinks work, but I have no clue how this fixed my issue. Can you elaborate on this?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried running it on a localhost? MAMP is a good option for this.
https://www.mamp.info/en/

Comment: How will it make a difference if I use MAMP instead of Docker? My problem remains the same: I don't have the same codebase which is being ran on wordpress.com, so I can't recreate the production environment locally.

Comment: @RobertoGeuke If you can't download all the files of the websites, you wont be able to create a closed development environment.

Comment: I was hoping someone else ran into the same issues as me and found a way how to run a wordpress.com hosted site locally (emphasis on wordpress.com hosted).